# Set week number of "1/2/2011(Sun)" as 52 of 2010?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, week-number

How can I set week number of "1/2/2011(Sun)" as 52 of 2010?

When I write as follows, it says week number is "1".

```
Dim dtTest As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, CDate("2012/01/02"), _
                                 FirstDayOfWeek.Monday, FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFullWeek)
```

Why is it? I set FirstDayOfWeek as Monday, so week number of "1/2/2011(Sun)" Should be 52, right?

"1/2/2011(Sun)" is just an example.

I want general method to do:
1. First day of week is Monday.
2. First week of year is the first full week which stat with Monday.
3. The last week of year should contain dates before the first week of the next year(such as 1/1/2011(Sat), 1/2/2011(Sun))

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, you have the year 2012 instead of 2011. 1/2/2011 gets week 52 with  `FirstDayOfWeek.Monday` and `FirstWeekOfYear.FirstFullWeek`

Comment: It happens to all of us, not being able to see the obvious.  I call it 'programmer blind'.  A couple of weeks ago I had to enter an IP address with a last octet of 242.  I entered 232, and even went so far as to retype the statement two times, and kept entering 232...

Comment: The simplest mistakes take the longest to fix.